# how to remove quotations from dataweave 2.0 script?

Tags: json, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule4

dataweave 2.0 script in Anypoint Studio 7.3 while building JSON always add quotations to the object, even if it's not value but new JSON object.

My code looks like this:

```html
%dw 2.0
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Strings
var studyId = vars.request.studyId
---
{[
    {
      (vars.keytype): value1,
      StudyId: value2
    },
    (vars.condition)
]}
```

where (vars.condition) is just another json object:

```
{"key1":"value"}
```

the Question is how to remove extra quotations surrounding (vars.condidtion)?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason for it to add extra quotes is that your `condition` variable doesn't have the `application/json` mime-type set.

Comment: I've solved this problem with workaround in Java. Payload --> String --> String.replace(String, String) but I'm not happy about this. I had so many problems working on JSONs on Mule4... Thanks anyway.